# Expo notifications can't call `getExpoPushTokenAsync()`

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, expo, expo-notifications

Am currently trying to setup notifications on my managed expo project

- Expo version `47.0.0`
- Expo notifications version `0.17.0`
- Device: Samsung Galaxy s10
- Android version `12`

I am currently just trying to get the basic setup itself working and retrieve my devices push token. This should be done using `Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()` as described [here](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/#api).

### The Problem

My error is strange, when I call `getExpoPushTokenAsync` it does indeed get me the expo push token, however shortly after my app crashes with the following messages

```
ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[1], "../../../src/util").types.isPromise')
 WARN  [expo-notifications] Error encountered while updating server registration with latest device push token. [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[5], "@ide/backoff").computeNextBackoffInterval')]
```

I have tried

- re-installing `node_modules` and `expo-notifications` but still get the same.
- I can definitely see the `@ide/backoff` package is installed in my `node_modules`.
- I also followed [these instructions](https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/using-fcm/) to setup firebase in app, even though my understanding is that it should work out of the box in expo go app while devving.

One other interesting thing is that I can call `Notifications.getDevicePushTokenAsync()` fine with no error. But still get the same error if i pass that in to `getExpoPushTokenAsync` method after. At a surface level it seems like somehow the request out to expo services to get the expo push token is both passing and failing ‍♂️

```js
const devicePushTokenResponse = await Notifications.getDevicePushTokenAsync();
const expoPushTokenResponse = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync({
  devicePushToken: devicePushTokenResponse,
}); // <--- Returns token & errors a few seconds later
```

Couldn't see any other posts with this error and `expo-notifications`, so would be keen to see if anyone else has ran into / fixed a similar issue recently

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I figured it out, it was somewhat hinted at by this line
`ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[1], "../../../src/util").types.isPromise')` 
And more specifically the fact that a `node_modules` dependency is referencing 3 levels up in the file system.

### The solution

Turns out that for some reason my module resolver (defined in `babel.config.js`) was resolving my project's `util` folder **instead of** the packages util  folder. I think this was compounded by my metro config making use of the `inlineRequires` functionality to improve performance ([see more](https://facebook.github.io/metro/docs/configuration/))

I am sure there is some actual config that could be updated to exclude `node_modules` from using inline requires (i did try use a blocklist to no avail), but as an interim, i was able to get it working fine by changing the path of my `util` folder to be `@my-project/util` so that it avoids future collisions.

Hope this helps anyone who runs into the same issue in the future :)